# Title Case for "e-commerce"

Tags: titles

When I write Powerpoint slides, I usually use [title case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Case_styles) for slide headers. I am a little unsure as to how to include [e-commerce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-commerce) in headers. Wikipedia stylizes it as "E-commerce" which seems inelegant. Any guidance on how to use hyphenated words in titles?

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia does that to all its subjects.  Don't take it seriously.  The e in e-commerce comes from the e in eMail back when people still cared about e and i prefixes.  They were always lower case.  Capitalized as E-commerce it doesn't make me think of electronics or the internet.  It makes me think of [E!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E!) or [Enron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enron).

Some words respond to changing their capitalization well.  This one doesn't.

e-Commerce evokes e-Mail which is old.  e-mail is newer and email newest.  Or laziest.  What's best depends on whether you want to be formal or hip.

Comment: So then what is your final recommendation? e-Commerce?

Comment: @fgnu see update